# entity relation object update

Tags: entity-framework

Please can you tell me where I am wrong. I had a following code:

```
public void UpdateClient(Client oClient)
    {                                        
        foreach(Mitarbeiter item in oClient.Mitarbeiters)
        {
            if (item.MiID==0)
            {                    
                context.Mitarbeiters.AddObject(item);                    
            }
            else {
                var key = context.CreateEntityKey("Mitarbeiters",item);
                object original;
                if (context.TryGetObjectByKey(key,out original))
                {
                    context.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName,item);
                }
            }
        }
        context.Clients.First(c => c.ClID == oClient.ClID);            
        context.Clients.ApplyCurrentValues(oClient);


       context.SaveChanges();
```

}
I received

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

when I add a new object to Mitarbeiters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your class `Mitarbeiter` has a navigation property to `Client` and it is not null when you run through the loop (so `item.Client != null`) then by adding `item` to the ObjectSet you also add the referenced `Client` into the context in state `Added`. (Adding an entity does not only add the entity itself but also all referenced entities which are not yet in the context.) Later (`context.Clients.First(c => c.ClID == oClient.ClID);`) you load the client a second time which is already in the context in `Added` state which is the reason for the exception.

Try to load the client into the context *before* you add `item`:

```
public void UpdateClient(Client oClient)
{                                        
    context.Clients.First(c => c.ClID == oClient.ClID);

    foreach(Mitarbeiter item in oClient.Mitarbeiters)
    {
        if (item.MiID==0)
        {                    
            context.Mitarbeiters.AddObject(item);                    
        }
        else {
            var key = context.CreateEntityKey("Mitarbeiters",item);
            object original;
            if (context.TryGetObjectByKey(key,out original))
            {
                context.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName,item);
            }
        }
    }
    context.Clients.ApplyCurrentValues(oClient);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Just a guess, I am not sure if this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Slauma, you are right. I just need to set item.Client = null before  call AddObject.